# Second conditional formatting clause overwriting the first

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I want to apply conditional formatting to this sheet, I want it to be Blue if column 5 is Project A and red if it is Project B

With the following code, the project A applies and then the project B overwrites it/deletes it.

That shouldn't happen because of splice, I think. What am I doing wrong?

If I remove lines 13 and 15 then I never get to see the first rule applied at all.

```
function Colors() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();

  var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A1:Z1000')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$E1="Project A"')
  .setFontColor('#0000FF')
  .build());

  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);

  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A1:Z1000')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$E1="Project B"')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, ..)` is removing the last item from the array <sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)</sup>. If the only item in that array is your previous formatting rule, you are *deleting the 'A' rule and replacing it with 'B'* with a new one.

If you just want to add a rule onto an array try the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function!

```
function Colors() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();

  var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A1:Z1000')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$E1="Project A"')
  .setFontColor('#0000FF')
  .build());

 //We can also remove this and do it all at once at the bottom!    
//spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);

  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A1:Z1000')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$E1="Project B"')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());

spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
}
```